# Why is my cosine similarity always positive? (fasttext)

Tags: numpy, trigonometry, similarity, fasttext

I'm trying to evaluate the cosine similarity of two vectors representing words. I'm using the pre-trained word vectors from fasttext.
Now, I'm wondering why my cosine similarity is always a positive number, no matter what word I'm using. Any suggestions?

Here's that part of my code. a and b are the word vectors.

```
def cos_sim(a, b):
   dot_product = np.dot(a, b)
   norm_a = np.linalg.norm(a)
   norm_b = np.linalg.norm(b)
   return dot_product / (norm_a * norm_b)
```

I'd be glad if someone could help me out, since I'm still quite on a beginner's level.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have posted above, it works as expected for me when I try it with `a = [1, 1]` and `b = [-1, -1]` (i.e. gives -1). 
So all the cosine similarities being positive is purely due to the word vectors. How did you come the conclusion that they are all positive? Did you try them all?
Also sklearn implementation for cosine similarity, no need to roll your own, [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html)

Comment: @Hiho Thanks for your reply! I tried about 70 words or more. So chances are low that it was just a coincidence.
One thing I'm also a bit confused about is the description of np.dot which is:
"If a is an N-D array and b is an M-D array (where M>=2), it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last axis of b:
`dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m])`
Is the dot product of n-dimensional (n>2) vectors always calculated like that?
I'll try the sklearn implementation too to check if it makes a difference.

Comment: I'm not sure with regards to the dot product, but why does this matter in this case, both a and b should be 1D?

Comment: @Hiho Ooooh! Yes, sorry! I thought that [1,2,3] would be 3D! Haven't coded for too long! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which fasttext dataset you are using, but I downloaded the 1M, 300 dimension wiki news one from [here](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/english-vectors.html), and using the example code below I def get some negative cosine similarity.

So you might just have to try for more word vectors, I don't think you are doing anything wrong as such though.

```
import io
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

ffp = "/path/to//wiki-news-300d-1M.vec"

def load_vectors(fname):
    fin = io.open(fname, 'r', encoding='utf-8', newline='\n', errors='ignore')
    n, d = map(int, fin.readline().split())
    data = {}
    for ix, line in enumerate(fin):
        tokens = line.rstrip().split(' ')
        data[tokens[0]] = list(map(float, tokens[1:]))

        if ix > 1000:
            break
    return data

data = load_vectors(ffp)
word_vectors = np.asarray(list(data.values()))

r = cosine_similarity(word_vectors[300:500, :], word_vectors[100:200])

print(r.min())
print(np.count_nonzero(r < 0))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort! When I'm running this code with my model it also returns that there are some negative cosine similarities... 1562 to be exact. Now I'm wondering how high the probability is that I just got positive values by chance. If I understood correctly, r consists of 20 000 cosine similarities. So the probability of one being negative would be 1562/20000=0.0781 which is quite low. So it could be alright that I'm not finding any negative cosine similarities when testing only 70 words. Please, correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Yes, I def think you are good and the 70 being all positive was just a coincide.